# acknowledgement part of thesis

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement

I am going to prepare the draft my Ph.D thesis and plan to submit it to my PhD advisor. Should I write the acknowledgement part in the first draft, or it must be written in the final draft?

Comment: That's very dependent on your local customs. In France I was advised that it's customary to only write the acknowledgments at the very last possible step (when you send the thesis to be printed basically), because it's in poor taste to thank people when you're not even sure that you will be granted the degree – but this may differ where you are. Why don't you just ask your advisor or colleagues? It's not like you can be expected to know this little tidbit of information that's useful exactly once in your life.

Comment: You could add a placeholder area/page(s) for acknowledgements. Showing that you are going to add it in, without actually having to write it out explicitly until the final draft.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by omitting it, show it to your advisor, and prepare to be asked to fill that part in immediately.  (Draft that section and store it on your computer so you'll have it ready to plop in if need be.)